# Sending mails with laravel for android app forgot password functionality

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to create a forgot password module for my android project which has laravel running as backend. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a random string and send it as a mail but I don't know how to do it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;

class FgtPswdController extends Controller
{
    public function CheckEmail(Request $request){

        $email = $request['email'];

        $checkEmail = App\Login::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

        if ($checkEmail){

            $randomString = str_random(6);
            App\Forgot_Password::where('email', $email)->update('reset_code', $randomString);
        }
        else{
            $response['verification'] = false;
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I send a mail using inbuilt functions of laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Mail::raw('Your Text', function($message){
            $message->to(to@host.com)->subject('Your Subject');
            $message->from('email@host.com', 'Your Name');
        });
```